# Gson Issue : Cannot map List<String> response to the Pojo class

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having a microservice based architecture. One of my service calls another service api, and mostly we share the response class object, which makes it easy to map using `gson.fromJson` method.

Now, the issue which I have is that from one of the microservice api, the response I get in my parent service is of the type `List<String>`. And the parent service response pojo class is of following format :

```
public class ParentResposneClass {
        private List<String> list;
        //getter-setter etc
}
```

The parent api call piece of code is following (have removed unnecessary part) :

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(postRequest);
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Logger.info(jsonResponse); // ["first","second"]
```

- **Problem 1**

Now, if I would want to map the jsonResponse to my pojo response class `ParentResposneClass` :

```
gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, ParentResposneClass.class);
```

I get the error : `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2`

And reason seems to be understandable. But my question is that is it possible to fix the above issue in this method.

- **Problem 2**

If I don't go the `gson` way, and instead directly set the list object in `ParentResposneClass` :

```
ParentResposneClass parentResposneClass = new ParentResposneClass();
parentResposneClass.setList(convertStringToList(jsonResponse)); 
System.out.println(parentResposneClass.getList());

public static List<String> convertStringToList(String str) {
        str = str..replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", ""));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(commaSepString.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        return list;
}
```

This gives response (`parentResposneClass.getList()`) as `"tag": ["\"first\"","\"second\""]` with all these escape showing the json encoded string is still being retained.

So, is there a good way to solve this escape character issue without just directly replacing these from string.

PS : I know its a design issue where both microservice should have had shared the same response classes. But given this situation, is there a way we can solve either `Problem 1` or `Problem 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1 I'd go:

```
var list = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType())
var prc = new ParentResponseClass()
prc.setList(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried something similar to this sometime back.

List result = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, List.class);

ParentResposneClass parentResposneClass = new ParentResposneClass();
parentResposneClass.setList(result);